# Passing datetime paramters in Dynamic SQL, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a property in a table called cdate which is stored as such: 2014-10-07 05:26:17.897.

my dynamic  query is something like this, CDATE is a datetime in the table and startdate and enddate  are always passed and they are both datetime as well. My where clause is in a dynamic SQL query and it returns some records but for instance  if CDate = 2014-10-07 05:26:17.897 and I am passing start date as 09/30/2010 08:15 pm and end date 10/07/2014 08:15 pm, i do not get my intended record back

```
SELECT  
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ServiceEntry.CDate,120) as CDate
FROM TABLE
WHERE
(Table.CDate between ''' + convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 120)  + '''  and   ''' +  convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 120) + ''')
```

**my original query**

```
DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT
       TSBNumber [TSBNumber],
       SystemFullName,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ServiceEntry.ClosedDate,120) as ClosedDate
     FROM ServiceEntry 
     inner JOIN System 
       ON ServiceEntry.SystemID = System.ID
     where
      (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber IS NOT NULL)
       AND 
       (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
       AND
       ( 
       (''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') OR
         (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber in (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''', ''' + ',' + ''')))
        )  
        AND (
         (''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') 
        OR(System.PlatformID = ''' + cast(@PlatformID as varchar(10)) + ''')
        OR(''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = ''' + '12' + ''' AND System.PlatformID <=  ''' + '2' + ''')
        )
        AND
   (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between ''' + convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 120)  + '''  and   ''' +  convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 120) + ''')
```

Comment: It is a DateTime in SQL Server 2008 table

Comment: I believe you need to convert `table.cdate` in the `where` clause the same as you have in the `select`.  and is @startdate ALWAYS before @ENDDate?  if not that's a problem and if @start or @end are NULL then you have a problem there as well... are you getting an error or just no results?

Comment: STartDate and EndDate will always be provided, the dates passed will have a timestamp in them. I get no results in the above use-case

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed this the first time... your converting  a `@startDate, @EndDate` to varchar in the where clause... why?  varchar datetime will seldom equal a true timestamp... which is why it's hit and miss... What are variables `@startDate, @endDate `defined as? and why convert them if they are not going to be rendered...  Basically you're saying.... Take this REAL apple turn it into a picture of an orange now have the system compare the Real apple passed in to the orange you created...

Comment: @tam tam , don't cast startdate and enddate in the where caluse

Comment: @xQbert startdatetime and enddatetime are both datetime and will always be passed to my query. The where clause is part of dynamic sql so if i dont do conversions i get this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Rajesh if i dont cast it in the where clause then I get this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Becuase the where clause is in a dynamic query

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` to `varchar` as you need `date` comparison

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ServiceEntry.CDate,120) as CDate
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE
    Table.CDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

EDIT:

AS OP wants in dynamic query it should be written like this

```
@query = ' Declare @StartDate datetime = ' + value1  + ' Declare @EndDate datetime =' + value2 + ' SELECT  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ServiceEntry.CDate,120) as CDate
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE
    Table.CDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate '

exec(@query)
```

Comment: where clause if you notice the syntax from my query it is in a dynamic query and if i dont cast it in the where clause then i get this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @tamtam, if it is dynamic query. it should be like this.

Comment: i have already decalred the startdate and endate in my store procedure, please look at my post, i edited and added the original query

Comment: @tamtam if you already declared, you can you use varchar(30) instead of 10 to fit time stamp too.

Comment: I changed it to (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between ''' + convert(varchar(30), StartDate, 120)  + '''  and   ''' +  convert(varchar(30), EndDate, 120) + ''')    
 and still the error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: can you give example value for startdate and enddate

Comment: start date 09/30/2014 04:15 pm  and end date 10/07/2014 04:15 pm. These values are being passed to the SP from a calendar control via the web app